# How to detect a method called in another bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I have two Java beans for my webapp: one is the userController and the other is the profileController. Both of them are conversation scoped. I want that when the current user in the userController is changed, the profileController detects the change and changes its current profile. How to achieve this?

Comment: The user can change inside a conversation?

Comment: Not being an expert on J2EE, but what about implementing the Observer pattern? It's lightweight and really simple to implement ;-)

Comment: I think the conversation is per browser tab isn't it? Or what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using the Observer Pattern.

[Observer Pattern Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

The ProfilerController should suscribe to UserController events.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a mechanism that listen each other. You can use Observer Pattern.